# asp.net membership provider get UserName by UserId

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have seen a lot of question asking about known user name and how to retrieve UserId accordingly. How about the other way around?

For some reason I have UserId, but I don't want to include aspnet_User table into my data entities. Is there any way I can retrieve the user name without querying against aspnet_User table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
if (user != null)
    string name = user.UserName;
```

Internally, this will access the ASP.NET user table. There's no way to avoid that.

Comment: How come I forgot this, Membership.GetUser((Guid)UserId); thanks buddy!